# Numbered heading in markdown

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have starting using jupyter notebook and jupyter lab, and in markdown cells the heading formatting is shown with numbers, how to have heading not to show numbers or better how to decide when and where to show heading numbers?

Answer (score 1):

In jupyter lab you can show the "Table of Content" view in the left pane. In the toolbar of the pane there is a button for "Toggle Auto Numbering"

In classic notebook interface I don't know how to do the same, but luckily I don't use classic notebook.